# Laravel direct auth attempt from custom form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a custom login form (slides out from the right side of the homepage) and I'm trying to directly log in from this form but it keeps redirecting to /login page. Is there a way to directly pass credentials on this form (mirrored after default /login form) to the Auth controller to be validated?

Comment: please share code so we can help

Comment: How are you executing the login request? Make sure its `/login` with `POST` method.